# Angular ngModel not matching any selectbox options

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a problem with selectboxes and an one-way-databinding via [ngModel] in angular:

If my model is storing a value that is not longer existing as an option, the selectbox still takes the value from the model and just shows an "empty" selected option and is valid (See this [`Plunker example`](https://plnkr.co/edit/FXG6nRJfUMyWNYFOav9A?p=preview)).

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? I would expect a different behavior, maybe not taking the value from the model at all or atleast marking the field as invalid. A selectbox shouldn't be valid if the value has no matching options in my opinion.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I am thinking about adding a custom Validator (that is checking if the value is in a given list or something like that), but i want to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular do not expose list of option values in form control better create options dynamically using some value map or list (something like dropValues=[1,2,3]) and match the value you trying to set against the map.
Its kind of you have to write your own custom validation.